# "Loyola Schools deployed x solution." or "Loyola School deployed x solution."

Tags: grammatical-number

If a school has two branches and the name of the school is Loyola School. A technology solution has been deployed in one of the branches. Which is the correct one?

Comment: You’ve capitalised “School(s)”. Does the word appear in the name of the school, and if so, does it have a trailing ‘s’?

Comment: Yes it appears in the name of the school- Loyola School

Comment: No the school doesn't have the trailing 's'. But if I want to write some blog about the school, should I write 'Loyola School' or 'Loyola Schhols'?

Comment: Loyola School, or Loyola High School (etc) (if specification is better).

Comment: I hope nobody got too wet with all those solutions being spilled — sorry, deployed. I'd suggest they leave them in their chemistry lab and get someone to teach English to the technologists.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your intent.

If you are talking about the corporate body called “Loyala School”, then use singular agreement, spelling the name in its official form. Since you are referring to the single entity, it doesn’t matter how many branches it has, just as it doesn’t matter how many teachers, buildings or classrooms it has.

If you are referring to each branch as a ‘school’ in its own right and you’re talking about multiple deployments, use plural agreement with “Loyola School branches”, or more informally, “Loyola schools”, where *schools* is used as a common noun, hence left uncapitalised.

Since you’re asking about a single branch deployment, you’re better off referencing the corporate entity in the singular and noting the branch separately:

- Loyola School deployed *X* solution (at its *Y* branch).